Boolean union, dyntopo and remesh. Object is partially shaded flat
I have an object that ended up becoming partially shaded flat again, by using, I think, the boolean union tool. I also remeshed certain areas and then used dyntopo for decreasing the topology. So I’m not sure exactly at which point one of the meshes that got united with the others, got shades flat again.
How do I shade it smooth again? I know shade smooth is a right click button menu, but that doesn’t work.
Is there another way Without ruining the rest of the new united mesh? The rest of the object, is shaded smooth.


You can use the windows snip tool or Blender itself to take a screen shot. Don't post photos of your computer monitor. It's hard for us to tell if what we're looking at is some part of your computer monitor or a result of the Blender software itself when you use that kind of image in your post.

You can't affect SmoothShade functionality in Sculpt mode. If you switch back to object mode the RMB menu will work again, you can shade it smooth there.
